# Get Smart Playlist to pick up tracks that are in playlists but not added to library?

Tags: music, music.app, playlist, smart-playlist

1. I have a folder of playlists "Weekly"
2. Inside there are manual playlists containing tracks I have added
3. Some of those tracks have been marked as favorites (starred)

I create a Smart Playlist, match all rules:

1. Playlist (is) "Weekly"
2. Favorite (is not) Favorited

Expected

- list of tracks that have not been marked as Favorite
- Should be 32 tracks

Actual

- Lists only 3 tracks
- At least they qualify in that they have not been "favorited"
- Only tracks that have also been "added to library"

Question

- How can I get Smart Playlists to list tracks that exist in playlists but have not been "added to libary"?
- Let's say, for now, that adding to library is not desired

What I've tried

- removing the "favorited" criteria (all tracks are listed, as expected)
- negating the "favorited" criteria (all favorited tracks are listed, as expected)

My setup

- Sonoma 14.3.1
- Music.app 1.4.3